# Update foreign key in MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to use this code:

```
alter table KUNDE 
(foreign key (`PostNr`) references POSTSTED(`Postnr`);
```

I receive this error message:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(foreign key (`PostNr`) references POSTSTED(`Postnr`)' at line 2

I dont understand what is wrong with my syntax. My input should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

The [correct `ALTER TABLE` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) uses the `ADD` keyword and no `()` surrounding the expression (only surrounding the columns).

```
alter table `KUNDE` ADD foreign key (`PostNr`) references `POSTSTED` (`Postnr`);
```

And as with any key, ensure that `KUNDE.PostNr` and `POSTSTED.Postnr` have the same data type, and that `POSTSTED.Postnr` is either a `PRIMARY KEY` or has an index defined otherwise.

Comment: Also, there's **PostNr** and **Postnr**. Check if the other tables has the same field name.

Comment: Depending on the coalition, they're most likely not case sensitive.

Comment: @DiH: No, column names are **not** case sensitive. See: [Identifier Case Sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) where it states ***"Column, index, stored routine, and event names are not case sensitive on any platform, nor are column aliases."***

Comment: Indeed, point taken. Sharing a resource for further reading on database identifiers and case-sensitivity: http://www.alberton.info/dbms_identifiers_and_case_sensitivity.html#.UR-RjqVBPg0